# sample does not stop on completion event

Tags: rx-java

I am executing an example from the book [Reactive Programming with RxJava](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do) on page 212/213:

```
Observable<String> names = Observable
        .just("Mary", "Patricia", "Linda", "Barbara",
                "Elizabeth", "Jennifer", "Maria", "Susan",
                "Margaret", "Dorothy");
Observable<Long> absoluteDelayMillis = Observable
        .just(0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1,
                3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6,
                4.4, 4.8)
        .map(d -> (long) (d * 1_000));
Observable<String> delayedNames = names
        .zipWith(absoluteDelayMillis,
                (n, d) -> Observable
                        .just(n)
                        .delay(d, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .flatMap(o -> o);
delayedNames
        .sample(1, SECONDS)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

When I run the code, the output is:

```
Linda
Barbara
Susan
Dorothy
```

According to the book (and also what I think), `Dorothy` should not be there, because `sample()` is supposed to forward the completion event @4.8s.

I am running the example with rxjava 1.1.6

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Sample` is kind of timer which ticks every certain amount of time and pick last item from "buffer".

In your case if you will modify your last observable in:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
delayedNames
        .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println(String.format("%s - %d", n, (System.currentTimeMillis() - time))))
        .sample(1, SECONDS)
        .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println(String.format("complete - %d", (System.currentTimeMillis() - time))))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

You will see output something like that:

```
Mary-155
Patricia-657
Linda-959
Linda
Barbara-1156
Barbara
Elizabeth-3355
Jennifer-3460
Maria-3558
Susan-3658
Susan
Margaret-4460
Dorothy-4856
Dorothy
complete - 4852
```

So lets go step by step.

- First tick happens at `1000`. As you can see in output, last item in buffer is `Linda`.
- Second tick happens at `2000`. Only `Barbara` is in buffer. Printing it.
- Third tick happens at `3000`. Nothing is in buffer.
- Forth tick happens at `4000`. `Susan` is last in buffer. Printing.
- Fifth tick happens at `5000`. `Dorothy` is last in buffer. Printing.

**UPD:**

Actually, there is no tick on `5000`, and seems `sample` will always emit last item in buffer. For example if you will modify source observables:

```
    Observable<String> names = Observable
            .just("Mary", "Patricia", "Linda", "Barbara",
                    "Elizabeth", "Jennifer", "Maria", "Susan");
    Observable<Long> absoluteDelayMillis = Observable.just(0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6)
```

It will print:

```
Mary - 153
Patricia - 654
Linda - 957
Linda
Barbara - 1157
Barbara
Elizabeth - 3358
Jennifer - 3457
Maria - 3559
Susan - 3658
Susan
complete - 3659
```

**UPD2:**

I've created [bug report](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4952)

**UPD3:**

I've checked and In rxjava2 it is working as expected.

Comment: I also think it's a bug, because according to the mable diagram in the [Observable.sample(Long, Timeunti) javadocs](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.6/rx/Observable.html#sample-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), the last item should not be emitted.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially caused a bug with RxJava that has been removed in the 2.0 release. Your understanding of the sample operator is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, this is not a bug with RxJava 1.x because this was a [requested behavior](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3657) back in early 2016.

However, this was overlooked within RxJava 2.x and as of 2.0.4 it doesn't emit the very last buffered item, just like the pre 1.1.3 version.

Unfortunately, there is no workaround but there is an [enhancement PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4955) posted that will allow choosing the mode for `sample`.

Comment: It is an error in RxJava 1.1.6 - just that it is not in the code, but in the java-documentation of [Observable.sample(Long, Timeunti)](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.6/rx/Observable.html#sample-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).
Also the book is erroneous, because it mentions that all examples should work with RxJava 1.1.6 (except otherwise noted-which is not the case for this example).